# How to find rpm binary of a given process?

Tags: command-line, centos, cron

Here is the problem: I'm trying to find what cron software is running on my machine, however question applies to any generic process. One  way to do it is:

Find the process

```
ps aux |grep cron
```

Find the link to binary

```
ls -la /proc/PID_FROM_ABOVE/exe
```

This is my case returned

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Jan 17 07:22 /proc/3363/exe -> /usr/sbin/crond
```

Now `crond` is just an executable. I'm interested in finding the `rpm` responsible for this executable. Is there any direct way?

I was able to estimate it was vixie-cron using

```
rpm -qa| grep cron
```

However, there has to be some better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or, if you prefer using rpm:

```
rpm -qf /usr/sbin/crond
```

Comment: @PunjCoder: this is faster and better in your case. It only works if the package is installed though, so you can't say "what would give me file X?" like you can with the yum option.

Answer (score 1):

`yum whatprovides /usr/sbin/crond`

or just `yum provides /usr/sbin/crond`

or even `yum provides */crond` for lazy people (me!)